# SOAP Unmarshalling Error from PHP Date -1 day

Tags: javascript, php, json, soap

Hi really stuck with this one - I think it's do to do with formatting I put in my XML request via PHP:

I minus 1 day from the input field Date_To by:

```
$last_night = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($_POST['date_to'])));
```

The API receives the request in correct form successfully but I believe this is still not the correct format for the date? it throws: `Unmarshalling Error: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'date'` regardless of being received and processed by the web server

$_POST['date_to'] is an input

```
<input type="date" name="date_to" />

var date_to_selector         = $(this).parent().find("input[name=date_to]");
var date_to = date_to_selector.val();
```

last_night is mentioned above, it converts to strtotime, -1day in format of date however, it is not accepted format as 'Date'

Sending POST request

Comment: It's pretty much impossible for anyone to answer this with only the information given - remember we don't know *anything* about your application which you don't tell us. What is in `$_POST['date_to']`? What does `$last_night` look like? Where does that error come from? What is the actual request your sending? Why have you tagged this with "JSON", "SOAP", and "JavaScript"? Please click [edit] and try to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: I've done that now

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I don't want to see where the data comes from, I want you to look at what the **value** of that data is. **You** need to do some debugging, and look at the **actual result** of the code you're writing. What values do you see in the variables? What does the XML that you're sending look like? Don't **widen** your search, **narrow** it: if the value in `$last_night` looks right, all code before that is irrelevant; if it's wrong, all code after that is irrelevant. This is the number 1 skill in debugging.

Comment: I've done several debugging methods in multiple browsers, debuggers, consoles etc

Format of date is exactly as I need it - YYYY-MM-DD

Result of code, I can do this in two ways - Post successfully however receive error 500 (posts successfully regardless) or like the above, "is not a valid value" - JSON tagged as parsing involved, SOAP involved as sending SOAP request, Javascript involved as JS format of data from input

Comment: **If** the value of `$last_night` is correct, then **every line before that point is irrelevant**. Forget about JavaScript, and browsers, and forms; forget about the line containing `date(...)` and `strtotime(...)` - you can replace all of that with `$last_night = '2021-11-21';` and it will make no difference at all. Your problem is somewhere **after** the code you've shown, when you try to **use** that date. I'm sure your **application** uses all the technologies you've tagged and more, but your **problem** is not related to them, so they are not relevant to anyone trying to help you.